# Error: "Spyder was unable to retrieve the value of this variable" after updating pandas to 1.4.0, how to solve it?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, debugging, spyder

Not sure if this is a common problem with `Spyder` after manually updating a package from `cmd` but, in my case, I updated `Pandas` package to `1.4.0` with `cmd`, before that everything was working perfectly, but after doing so, my `Spyder` environment threw the following error when trying to display a simple `df`:

[image]

The code I ran was:

```
import pandas as pd

#column names
column_names = ["Time", "Currency", "Volatility expected", "Event", "Actual", "Forecast", "Previous"]

#create a dataframe including the column names
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
```

It's important to mention that if I type `df` in the spyder console, I DO get the information stored in the `df` variable:

[image]

My only problem is that I can't see the details of that df when I click it in the `Variable Explorer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [my issue will be solved at the end of this month](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17342).

So, I had to downgrade my Pandas package to `1.3.5` version using `pip install -Iv --user pandas==1.3.5` on `cmd`, and `conda install pandas==1.3.5` on my `miniconda3` environment.

After that, my variable explorer ran smoothly:

[image: solucionado]

Answer (score 2):

This problem has plagued me for such a long time, but it persists after Pandas 1.4.0 if you are using Spyder in a virtual environment, as recommended by the Spyder docs. I found a simple solution.

Here is my basic environment:

**Spyder Environment**

Spyder, version 5.4.5

Python, version 3.10.4

**Working Environment**

Spyder-Kernels, version 2.4.4

Python, version 3.11.7

Pandas, version 2.1.4

If you read through the github issues thread link below, you will learn that when you call an variable through the variable explorer, that variable type must be supported by the environment that Spyder is installed in. So, this means if you are having trouble opening up a dataframe in Spyder, then it is likely that Pandas wasn't installed in your Spyder environment.

Run `conda install pandas` in your Spyder environment, then restart Spyder. Your finished! Of course, if your having trouble with a different data type, then you need to install the correct package for that class.

GitHub thread here:
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/15998